# autoconf, how to include file from AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR file

Tags: include, autotools, autoconf, m4

I would like to be able to merge two files into one during configure run.  I already do textural replacement using `AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR[file.hpp]` macro on some files.  is there some directive to include files from `file.hpp.in`, some sort of `@include (another.hpp) @` or something like that?

Thanks

Comment: I think you mean `AC_CONFIG_FILES` not `_SRCDIR`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer myself. file insertion can be done using [ac_subst_file](http://www.dis.com/gnu/autoconf/Setting-Output-Variables.html).

Answer (score 4):

`AC_CONFIG_FILES([file.hpp:file.hpp.in:another.hpp.in])` will perform text substitution on both `file.hpp.in` and `another.hpp.in` and then concatenate both results into `file.hpp`.

Comment: thanks, I did actually mean SRCDRI.  I found out how to do it, going to post it now